# Fixed sidenav and nav bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I need to create
[next view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L77vG.png)

but with fixed nav and sidenav using bootstrap.

could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<style>
.sidebar{
 height: 500px;
 border: thin black solid;
 
}

.nav_menu{
 border: thin red solid;
}

.content{
 border: thin green solid;
 height: 430px;
}



</style>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
 Your side bar content
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav_menu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
  <div class="col-md-12 content">
   Your Content
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

is this the same that you want?

Comment: Yes, my view should look like you propose.
But when I scroll content, sidebar and navigation should be fixed. Try to change your content height to 1200px.

Comment: then you can use CSS Property called `position:fixed` , to sidebar and navigation menu. did you try it?

Comment: yes, I tried it. thanks, I have found that I can use apex for my case.